# FFMPEG: How to chose a stream from all stream

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, dvb

I try to convert a **UDP** stream (that genrated from DVB signal) to **HLS** m3u8 file with this code:

```
ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001 -acodec aac -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -hls_wrap 100 -f hls /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

UDP stream contain 1 channel (in this case IRIB-TV1).

When I run this above code, **ffmpeg** detect all of service and channel that streamed from DVB card with this message:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://239.1.2.1:60001':
Duration: N/A, start: 77906.812644, bitrate: N/A
Program 101 
Metadata:
  service_name    : IRIB-TV1
  service_provider: IRIB
Stream #0:0[0x3f2]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x3f3](per): Audio: aac_latm ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Program 102 
Metadata:
  service_name    : IRIB-TV2
  service_provider: IRIB
Program 103 
Metadata:
  service_name    : IRIB-TV3
  service_provider: IRIB
Program 104 
Metadata:
  service_name    : IRIB-TV4
  service_provider: IRIB
```

As you see ffmpeg finf 4 channel in UDP stream, But VLC play only channel 1(IRIB-TV1).

Now I have have 2 question:

1-Can I get all channel and service via this **ffmpeg** code?

2-Can I choose a special stream from this **ffmpeg** code?(I know that ffmpeg can choose a stream with **-map** option but I want to choose other service_name that in output log)

**output file is** :

```
 ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-timeout' ... matched as AVOption 'timeout' with argument '6000000'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input file with argument 'udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'ultrafast'.
Reading option '-flags' ... matched as AVOption 'flags' with argument '-global_header'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'hls'.
Reading option '-hls_time' ... matched as AVOption 'hls_time' with argument '20'.
Reading option '-hls_wrap' ... matched as AVOption 'hls_wrap' with argument '5'.
Reading option '/var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8' ... matched as output file.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input file udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000.
[udp @ 0x1967040] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] Format mpegts probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] stream=0 stream_type=1b pid=3f2 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] stream=1 stream_type=11 pid=3f3 prog_reg_desc=
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:14476 seeks:0
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] parser not found for codec none, packets or times may be invalid.
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] probing stream 1 pp:2500
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] Probe with size=853, packets=1 detected loas with score=51
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] probed stream 1
[aac_latm @ 0x199e4e0] initializing latmctx
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] Frame num gap 397 393
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] Frame num gap 397 394
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] Frame num gap 397 395
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] mmco: unref short failure
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] number of reference frames (0+4) exceeds max (3; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no picture ooo
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] Increasing reorder buffer to 2
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no picture ooo
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] no picture 
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5034667 microseconds
[mpegts @ 0x1977380] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 1142476 bytes read:1143604 seeks:0 frames:397
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000':
  Duration: N/A, start: 43581.024200, bitrate: N/A
  Program 101 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : IRIB-TV1
      service_provider: IRIB
    Stream #0:0[0x3f2], 274, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 1/50, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x3f3](per), 123, 1/90000: Audio: aac_latm ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
  Program 102 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : IRIB-TV2
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 103 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : IRIB-TV3
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 104 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : IRIB-TV4
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 105 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : IRIB-TV5
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 106 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : IRINN
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 107 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : AMOOZESH
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 108 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : QURAN
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 119 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : SALAMAT
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 120 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : NASIM
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 151 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO IRAN
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 152 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO PAYAM
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 153 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO JAVAN
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 154 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO MAAREF
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 155 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO QURAN
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 156 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO FARHANG
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 157 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO SALAMAT
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 158 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO VARZESH
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 159 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO EGHTESAD
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 160 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO TEHRAN
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 161 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO AVAA
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 162 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO NAMAYESH
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 163 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO SABA
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 164 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : English Radio World Service
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 166 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Arabic Radio World Service
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 167 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO BAHARAN
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 169 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO TELAVAT
      service_provider: IRIB
  Program 170 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RADIO GOFTEGO
      service_provider: IRIB
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output file /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option f (force format) with argument hls.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8.
Successfully opened the file.
[mpegts @ 0x1967180] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 0x1967180] muxrate VBR, pcr every 2 pkts, sdt every 200, pat/pmt every 40 pkts
Output #0, hls, to '/var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/90000: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 1/25, q=2-31, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1(per), 0, 1/90000: Audio: aac_latm ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[NULL @ 0x199cc60] Current profile doesn't provide more RBSP data in PPS, skipping
[AVIOContext @ 0x19a9860] Statistics: 0 seeks, 896 writeouts=N/A    
[hls @ 0x1a65ca0] EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
[AVIOContext @ 0x1d162e0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x1966b40] Statistics: 0 seeks, 27 writeouts
[hls @ 0x1a65ca0] EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
[AVIOContext @ 0x199b7a0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
frame=  826 fps= 69 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:20.63 bitrate=N/A    
video:2611kB audio:68kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (udp://239.1.2.1:60001?fifo_size=50000):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 872 packets read (2779202 bytes); 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 405 packets read (69222 bytes); 
  Total: 1277 packets (2848424 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (/var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 826 packets muxed (2673485 bytes); 
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 405 packets muxed (69222 bytes); 
  Total: 1231 packets (2742707 bytes) muxed
0 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x1967ce0] Statistics: 3884832 bytes read, 0 seeks
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Comment: Do you wish to select Program 102 or 103..etc? Also, ffmpeg is only showing content streams for Program 101. Don't know if that's due to tuning or is that the only one available.

Comment: @Mulvya Yes i wish to select Program 102 or 103..etc, i think becuase ffmpeg found other PID such as 102 or 103 , it can sream it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax as per the [docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) (example 8) is

```
ffmpeg -i udp://239.1.2.1:60001 -map 0:p:102 -acodec aac -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -hls_wrap 100 -f hls /var/www/html/ts/1.m3u8
```

but I don't see any streams declared for programs after 101, so check that they are available.

Comment: this option not work -map 0:p:102 ...i think -map work on a stream not on a PID

Comment: about "but I don't see any streams declared for programs after 101, so check that they are available"....if you get a stream from source such as vlc you dont see other PID but if you recive from a source such as mumudvb taht stream a dvb channel ...you can see other PID's

Comment: do you know how to send service_name to client?

Comment: when i use -map 0:p:102, ffmpeg show a warining "Trailing options were found on the commandline."

Comment: i found 1 other thing...if start stream with mumudvb i can see list of program that i sayed in first post...if stream channel with dvblast i cant see that ...meahs that mumudvb udp is diffrence that dvblast stream!

Comment: Show the console output for the command which produced the "trailing options." message.

Comment: Don't remove the command from the report file. Add `-analyzeduration 10M` before `-i`. Also, what does your dvblast output config say?

Comment: if i use dvblast i dont see program list , i mean this list Program 101 
Metadata:
  service_name    : IRIB-TV1
  service_provider: IRIB
Stream #0:0[0x3f2]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x3f3](per): Audio: aac_latm ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Program 102 
Metadata:
  service_name    : IRIB-TV2
  service_provider: IRIB
Program 103 
.........

Comment: What's streaming the input into ffmpeg?

Comment: i write inout stream in ffmpeg in question, mumudvb and dvblast scan stream udp, but i think there are some dif between output udp of dvblast and mumudvb becuase in dvblast udp stream's program list not show